# 403 Forbidden Error on subdomain

Tags: permalinks, subdomains

I've got a bit a troublesome issue.  In my development site installed at a subdomain http://staging.broadwayselect.com I'm getting 403 errors on all pages except my homepage.

Clicking on 'Discounts' in the main menu or 'Contact' in the footer menu you'll see these occur (other links are # at present).  I've gone through things with GoDaddy and it does not seem to be issues with .htaccess.

I've de-activated all plugins and changed to twentyfifteen theme and I still have the same error.

Originally it occurred when I tried to modify the permalink structure.

To access the [dev site](http://staging.broadwayselect.com)! you'll need these credentials. User: havefun pw: inthesandbox

The one things which I'm suspicious about is that the 403 error reads
`You don't have permission to access /BroadwaySelect/staging/contact/ on this server.`
while the url is http://staging.broadwayselect.com/contact.  This would seem to suggest to me perhaps something is up with the subdomain forwarding?

Any help or tips would be awesome.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue had to do with File permissions.  I believed that I had already checked into this to make sure that permissions were set properly, but I must have erred.

I went to the subdomain folder 'staging' which contains my WP install and turned on User 'read' and 'write' permissions, which were inactive. So now Web User and Owner permissions have been all set with read, write and execute permission.

Hope that helps someone!